# Fullcalendar 6 eventBackgroundColor work only on timeGridWeek

Tags: fullcalendar

Try to add background color to event, but it work only on `timeGridWeek` ,

this is a part of my code:

```
var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        headerToolbar: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
        },
        //fuso orario locale lo prende dal browser
        timeZone: 'local',
        //italiano
        locale: 'it',
        events: '<?=base_url('userCalendar/event') ?>',
        //colore sfondo evento 
        eventBackgroundColor: 'red',
        editable: true,

        //vista iniziale
        initialView:'timeGridWeek',
```

I use a bootstrap template, if I `ispetionate` the code I can see that the event have a bootstrap anchor `css` rules.

Comment: Check out https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventDisplay - if you have a timed event then in the dayGrid view it won't have a solid background by default

Comment: There is a way to change dinamically background color f.e. by user color ?

Comment: You can set the the colour individually for each event (in the event data), or for each event source.

Comment: which is the data must i  return in event?

Comment: Did you check the documentation? https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-parsing